# JqGrid export to excel from client side

Tags: excel, jqgrid

I was wondering if there was any in-built  export to excel functionality in the JQGrid that would allow me to export the grid data to csv or xls? To be clearer, I would not want to hit the server at all as the grid is loadOnce:true and would want to do it from the client side.

I am talking about some options in the jqgrid which would help me specify the filename and path as well as the file format

Sriram

Answer (score 0):

I use next steps

1.- I import this script https://gist.githubusercontent.com/xola139/0ee40653d17af327573e/raw/1595e8d74e83caf1ae5a50454188498727715415/ScriptExportExcelTable in your project

2.-After put a tag  where exist jqgrid, something like that

```
 where 

 nameMyJqgrid= name asig for you jqgrid
 name Ramdom= any name for you tab sheet in excel
```

3.-Finish

I hope you will be useful, regards